# Product symmetry matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric $n×n$ matrices.Prove that $AB = BA$ if and only if $AB$ is also symmetric.**

So we need to prove that AB is symmetric. This means $(AB)^T=AB$. 
Recall a property of transposes: the transpose of a multiplication is the multiplication of transposes. Thus $(AB)^T=(B^T)(A^T)$. But $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. Thus $A^T=A$ and $B^T=B$. So $(AB)^T=AB$.
 I get stuck here can somebody help me here??

Comment: Actually $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB=BA$, then we have $(AB)^T = B^T A^T = BA = AB$.

If $AB=(AB)^T$, then we have $AB=(AB)^T = B^T A^T = BA $.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1)\;\;AB=BA\;:\;\implies (AB)^t=B^tA^t=BA=AB\implies AB\;\;\text{symmetric}$$

$$(2)\;\;AB\;\;\text{symmetric}\;:\;\implies BA=B^tA^t=(AB)^t=AB$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A=A^T, B=B^T$, we obtain $$AB-BA=AB-B^TA^t=AB-(AB)^T$$, which proofs the statement.